# What is the relevance of the Generic Repository Pattern in .Net Core with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I am trying (and failing) to understand the purpose of the Generic Repository Pattern in the specific instance where it is wrapped around Entity Framework or EF Core.

what is the benefit of writing this:

```
public void Update(T obj)
{
    DbContext.Set<T>().Attach(obj);
    DbContext.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

When you get the same and more by simply writing it as

```
public void Update(Movie obj)
{
    DbContext.Set<Movie>().Attach(obj);
    DbContext.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

or

```
public void Update(Movie obj)
{
    var movie = DbContext.Movies.FirsOrDefault(x => x.MovieId == obj.MovieId);
    DbContext.Entry(movie).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj);
    DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I guess my real question is why do we wrap a generic repo around what is basically already a generic repository (with more features and optimisations)?

Comment: None - it's an antipattern for *all* ORMs, not just EF Core. For example that `Update` can perform 3 deletions and 5 insertsion along with 15 updates on unrelated objects too.

Comment: You do that when you want to abstract things or when the implementation might change (e.g. using something other than EF), especially in a DDD context. Although I'll have to agree that it almost serves no purpose...

Comment: I keep posting links to Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) so I don't have to write the same stuff every time.

Comment: @Haytam that's what DbSet and DbContext are about. The Generic Repository comes from a time before ORNs

Comment: @Haytam with ORMs, there's no need for a *generic* repository. All those methods are already available by the ORM itself. Abstracting things requires *specialized* repositories, that could abstract the multiple ORM operations that may be needed to serve a business operation

Comment: A DbContext implements UoW already - `SaveChanges` persists *all* changes. If you want to discard the entire UoW, just don't call `SaveChanges`. A DbSet *is* a repository - it already offers all the operations a "generic" repository does.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I definitely agree with you. I was explaining the reason people might give when you ask them this. Like I said, having a generic repository on top of EF (which already does the job) almost serves no purpose.

Comment: Beyond the correctness problems expressed by Peipman, another serious problem is that calling `SaveChanges` on every operation, you can no longer use DbContext as a UoW. Now you need a database transaction, a long-running one too, to be able to reverse changes. Database transactions though require an open connection so now you *lose disconnected operations*. It's back to 1995, before OLEDB's Disconnected Recordsets.

Comment: That's my view too, and if you wanted to cancel out of a series of SaveChanges because of an error condition, you can simply wrap your whole sequence in a Transaction, which you can quickly retrieve from DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction(SomeIsolationLevel); There's your Unit Of Work right there.

Comment: Long-running transactions in turn leads to blocking, conflicts, deadlocks and general performance eradication. Even if you use multi-version concurrency in PostgreSQL or Snapshot isolation in SQL Server, you still put a huge strain on the server as it has to copy and retrieve row versions

Comment: In the real world, I only ever use SaveChanges multiple times when saving a new entry, and then subsequently saving a bunch of related items which has its primary key as a foreign key.

Comment: And MVCC can't handle concurrent modifications anyway. That's why optimistic concurrency was introduced in the late 90s.

Comment: @CaptainKenpachi even this scenario is already covered. It's no different than how persisting a DataSet with new related rows would persist all new elements in their proper order.

Comment: If you guys post slightly longer versions of your comments as answers, I'll give each one of them a +10

Comment: That's why I posted the link to Peipman's article. Writing a *good* answer with all that takes time - about 1 hour I'd say, and I *have* written similar answers multiple times. An answer has to have structure and flow, especially when it has to target a common misconception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without being too presumptuous, I would like to answer my own question based off of the comment thread.

The generic repository pattern is a hold-over from the days before the era of Object-Relational Mappers (ORM's) like Entity Framework, xHibernate, Dapper, PetaPoco and a million others.

With the advent of the ORM, all the features found in the Repository Pattern are encapsulated within the ORM itself.

For instance, Entity Framework by default uses a Transaction/UnitOfWork each time you call `.SaveChanges()` on the DbContext.

It also automatically tracks changes made to entities returned by a query unless you *explicitly* tell it not to with `UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)`.

As far as Generic Repositories are concerned, what do you think the following code is:

```
MyDbContext.Set<WeatherForecast>().Add(forecast);
```